# Why use a "listener rect" to set up zooming in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've got a d3 (v5) visualization comprised of a DOM structure which looks more or less like `svg > g > etc`. I've set up a zoom listener on the svg like so:

```
this.svg.call(this.zoom.scaleExtent([1/2, 40]).on("zoom" zoomed))
```

In the "zoom" handler I'm transforming the underlying `g` node which is a direct child of `svg`. I see lots of examples and tutorials which set up a `rect` for the sole purpose of capturing mouse events. I've seen tutorials which do this, despite having an `svg` which already covers the surface of the viewport. Why is having the `rect` necessary/beneficial? Why not just use the `svg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the safest way to make sure mouse events are captured across the entire viewport. When a mouse event occurs the browser will do [hit-testing](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#hit-testing) to determine which element becomes a target of that event. It is important to understand that only [graphics elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermGraphicsElement) are considered during hit-testing, and thus, neither `<svg>` nor `<g>` elements can become direct targets of mouse events although an event may eventually reach them when it bubbles up to it.

If you had a standalone SVG (i.e. one that is not part of the HTML DOM tree) the spec defines rigorously:

> Note that the ‘svg’ element is not a graphics element, and in a Conforming SVG Stand-Alone File a rootmost ‘svg’ element will never be the target of pointer events, though events can bubble to this element.

Things are a bit different for embedded SVG documents, though:

> This specification does not define the behavior of pointer events on the rootmost ‘svg’ element for SVG images which are embedded by reference or inclusion within another document, e.g., whether the rootmost ‘svg’ element embedded in an HTML document intercepts mouse click events; future specifications may define this behavior, but for the purpose of this specification, the behavior is implementation-specific.

Placing a full scale `<rect>` spanning the entire viewport to intercept mouse events ensures that the hit-testing will work not depending on the SVG's surroundings nor the user agent (e.g. the browser) it is displayed in.

Comment: do we then have to do a `rect.call(d3.zoom())`, the `rect` will hide the svg, or will the event bubble up if the `rect` has no handlers

Comment: @rioV8 The event will bubble wether there is a handler or not. That way it can be handled by multiple handlers on the way up the DOM tree. The only way to stop it from bubbling is to call `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. That being said, both ways will work: you can assign a handler to `<rect>` or `<svg>`. The best option will likely be determined by the rest of your SVG and what you are trying to achieve. In terms of D3, though, you'll most often see it attached to the `<rect>`: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957.

Comment: @rioV8 Further reference on the event lifecycle: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing.

Comment: I want to note that I ran into one issue with using `rect` in that if I have other graphics elements which should be the target of mouse events, `rect` blocks them from being able to receive those events. I suppose this is why examples like https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3127661b6f13f9316be745e77fdfb084 show the zoom handler being attached to the `svg` itself.